# Need to switch to circular gradient from linear gradient (radial does not work for this) - CSS, JavaScript, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, gradient, gauge

I'm trying to create a gauge to display colours that are not in a linear gradient fashion.  I want the last bit on the colour gradient to essentially be pointing to the origin of the gauge, and this to have a slightly slanted gradient depending where on the gauge the colour stops.

The blue line below is what gradient I want to create.  If you want to play with the colours just exchange `color0`,`color1` etc with any hexadecimal colour.  All are grey except the first one is red.

Thanks for any advice!

[Gauge with linear gradient. Blue line indicates desired gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UJVr.png)

[image]

```js
am5.ready(function() {

  // Create root element
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
  var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

  // Set themes
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
  root.setThemes([
    am5themes_Animated.new(root)
  ]);

  // Create chart
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/radar-chart/
  var chart = root.container.children.push(
    am5radar.RadarChart.new(root, {
      panX: false,
      panY: false,
      startAngle: 180,
      endAngle: 360
    })
  );

  // Create axis and its renderer
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/radar-chart/gauge-charts/#Axes
  var axisRenderer = am5radar.AxisRendererCircular.new(root, {
    innerRadius: -10,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWidth: 15,
    strokeGradient: am5.LinearGradient.new(root, {
      rotation: 0,
      stops: [{
          color: am5.color('#f50223')
        }, // Use the color0 variable
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        }, // Use the color1 variable
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        }, // Use the color2 variable
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D4D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D3D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D3D3D3')
        },
        {
          color: am5.color('#D3D3D3')
        }
      ]
    })
  });

  var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
    am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
      maxDeviation: 0,
      min: -1,
      max: 1,
      strictMinMax: true,
      renderer: axisRenderer
    })
  );

  // Add clock hand
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/radar-chart/gauge-charts/#Clock_hands
  var axisDataItem = xAxis.makeDataItem({});
  axisDataItem.set("value", 0);

  var bullet = axisDataItem.set("bullet", am5xy.AxisBullet.new(root, {
    sprite: am5radar.ClockHand.new(root, {
      radius: am5.percent(99)
    })
  }));

  xAxis.createAxisRange(axisDataItem);

  axisDataItem.get("grid").set("visible", false);

  // Function to set a specific value for the clock hand
  function setClockHandValue(newValue) {
    axisDataItem.set("value", newValue);
  }

  // Call the function to set the clock hand value to a specific value
  setClockHandValue(0.5); // Change 50 to your desired value

}); // end am5.ready()
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/radar.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: @ralph.m unfortunately, there is no answer as of yet :(

Comment: @ralph.m You seem to have linked to the same post that the OP has included and to which the OP has gotten the code for this question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have deleted the previous post and made this one easier to understand in hope that it helps